# How to print struct's data continuously in linked list

Tags: c

I try to print all struct's name and grade, but it's failed.
I have no idea to fix it.
There is no error.

Purpose:
This is my practice about linked list.
I try to combine array initialize and use linked list.
So, the why "Node" struct has "Group" struct.
I'm newbie in software, so I don't know how to design the architecture in my practice.

I expect the output should be like this.

```
    mike    17
    john    19
    mary    21
```

But it's actually like this.

```
    mike    17
```

As following is my program.
**struct**

```
typedef struct t_group Group;
struct t_group{
  char *name;
  int grade;
};

typedef struct t_node Node;
struct t_node{
  Group classmate[3];
  Node *next;
};

//create three pointer
Node *head, *now, *previous;
Node arr = {"mike",17,
            "john",19,
            "mary",21};
```

**main function**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  //create linked list
  int num = 3;
  for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    now = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head = &arr;
    if (i==0){
      head = now;
    }else{
      previous->next = now;
    }
    now->next = NULL;
    previous = now;
  }
  now = head;

  //print linked list data
  Node *node = head;
  if(head == NULL){
    printf("List is empty\n");
  } else{
    while(node!=NULL){
      printf("%s\t",now->classmate->name);
      printf("%d\n",now->classmate->grade);
      node = node->next;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

where should I modify in this program?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages. Only tag the language you're actually programming in. Even though C and C++ might seem similar, they are actually *very* different languages.

Comment: The initialization of `arr` doesn't make sense. And I'd argue that the `t_node` structure itself doesn't make sense. Why does the `t_node` structure have an *array* for `classmate`? What is the purpose of your program? What is your assignment oe exercise? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: You don't really have the structures you need for the linked list.  Each node in the linked list should contain a single (name, grade) pair.  Instead, you have an array of three (name, grade) pairs in *each* node.  Each node should contain a single `Node` and a `next` pointer.

Comment: I add my purpose. Thank for your reminder.

Comment: @TomKarzes  I got it. I will think it. Thanks.